# How to use SqlBulkCopyColumnMappingCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlbulkcopy, columnmappings

I want to make one SqlBulkCopy method that I can use for all my bulk inserts by passing in specific data through the parameters.

Now I need to do mapping on some of them. I don't know how to make a SqlBulkCopyColumnMappingCollection since that was my plan to pass in the mapping collection in and use it. However I don't know how to make it. I can't make a new object of it.

This is what I have now. How can I add it do mapping put pass it in?

```
public void BatchBulkCopy(DataTable dataTable, string DestinationTbl, int batchSize)
{
    // Get the DataTable 
    DataTable dtInsertRows = dataTable;

    using (SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
    {
        sbc.DestinationTableName = DestinationTbl;

        // Number of records to be processed in one go
        sbc.BatchSize = batchSize;

        // Finally write to server
        sbc.WriteToServer(dtInsertRows);
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot add SqlBulkCopyColumnMappingCollection  to bulkCopy.ColumnMappings as later is get only. you can use Add method of bulkCopy.ColumnMappings to add mappings one at a time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't need to create a new instance of it - the SqlBulkCopy class has a property which is a mapping collection that you can use:

```
public void BatchBulkCopy(DataTable dataTable, string DestinationTbl, int batchSize)
{
    // Get the DataTable 
    DataTable dtInsertRows = dataTable;

    using (SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
    {
        sbc.DestinationTableName = DestinationTbl;

        // Number of records to be processed in one go
        sbc.BatchSize = batchSize;

        // Add your column mappings here
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("field1","field3");
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("foo","bar");

        // Finally write to server
        sbc.WriteToServer(dtInsertRows);
    }    
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on the comments, the goal was to make a generic function, e.g. not have to hardcode the mapping explicitly in the function.  Since the ColumnMappingCollection cannot be instantiated, I would recommend passing a `List<string>` or similar that contains the column mapping definition into the function.  For example:

```
var columnMapping = new List<string>();
columnMapping.Add("field1,field3");
columnMapping.Add("foo,bar");
```

Then re-define the function as

```
public void BatchBulkCopy(DataTable dataTable, string DestinationTbl, int batchSize, List<string> columnMapping)
{
    // Get the DataTable 
    DataTable dtInsertRows = dataTable;

    using (SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
    {
        sbc.DestinationTableName = DestinationTbl;

        // Number of records to be processed in one go
        sbc.BatchSize = batchSize;

        // Add your column mappings here
        foreach(var mapping in columnMapping)
        {
            var split = mapping.Split(new[] { ',' });
            sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(split.First(), split.Last());
        }

        // Finally write to server
        sbc.WriteToServer(dtInsertRows);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am aware of that however. Now you just tied this method to a single table(Unless I have every single table with the same column names).  I am trying to make a generic method here that I can pass in any table and do a sqlbulkcopy. So if I need 5 different sqlbulkcopy inserts I don't have 5 of these methods with almost the same code except for the mapping.

Comment: Given that the function should be generic, and you can't instantiate the ColumnMappingCollection, I'd recommend passing in a representation of the mapping - see the edit above.

Comment: Ya that's the way I figured out too expect I just send in a List of ColumnMappings instead of strings.