# XML-mapping to SQL-server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, entity-framework

I want to map a xml file to a SQL Server table.

This is what I've done so far:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("navetout.xml");
XmlNodeType type;

while (reader.Read())
{
    type = reader.NodeType;

    if(type == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
    }
}

//using Entity framework
static void writeToDatabase()
{
    BumsEntities _bums = new BumsEntities();

    _bums.Seamen.Add(new Seamen
                     {
                        PersonalIdentityNumber = "",
                        ReferedCivicRegistrationNumber = "",
                        UnregistrationReason = "",
                        UnregistrationDate = "",
                        MessageComputerComputer = "",
                        GivenNameNumber = "",
                        FirstName = "",
                        MiddleName = "",
                        LastName = "",
                        NotifyName = "",
                        NationalRegistrationDate = "",
                        NationalRegistrationCountyCode = "",
                        NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode = "",
                        NationalRegistrationCoAddress = "",
                        NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1 = "",
                        NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 = "",
                        NationalRegistrationPostCode = "",
                        NationalRegistrationCity = "",
                        NationalRegistrationNotifyDistributionAddress = "",
                        NationalRegistrationNotifyPostCode = "",
                        NationalRegistrationNotifyCity = "",
                        ForeignDistrubtionAddress1 = "",
                        ForeignDistrubtionAddress2 = "",
                        ForeignDistrubtionAddress3 = "",
                        ForeignDistrubtionCountry = "",
                        ForeignDate = "",
                        BirthCountyCode = "",
                        BirthParish = "",
                     });

    _bums.SaveChanges();
}
```

The code above is the database columns. What I want to be able to do is to load the xml file and insert the tags into the columns. The problem is that I don't know how to "translate" the xml tags to the database columns.. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: "_bums" "Seamen" (゜-゜)

Comment: Which language are you doing this in, btw? I suppose C#? You might wanna tag with that (and entity framework).

Comment: @G_H Seamen is the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the entire code, however should help :

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("navetout.xml");
DataSet ds = new DataSet("XML Data");
ds.ReadXml(reader);

// Create Database Connection here

foreach(DataTable dt in ds.Tables){

//save datatable to database - You can use SqlBulkCopy

}
```

[Saving DataTable to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469349/mapping-columns-in-a-datatable-to-a-sql-table-with-sqlbulkcopy)

Comment: Thanks. What connection do you mean in "//Create connection here"?

Comment: What do you mean with saving datatable to database? I want to save XML to database. How I can translate the XML-tags to database columns?