# Optimal ways to read data from excel and save in sql server DB c#

Tags: c#, excel, entity-framework

What is the optimal way to read data from excel and update in sql server DB.
Column name in excel is different from column name in DB.

am currently using Oledb drivers to read data from excel and ef 5.0 for db operations.

is there a better way of doing it?

excel contains close to 100 thousands rows

Comment: What do you mean by "lac"?

Comment: SQL Server includes SSIS since version 7 in the 1990s. Entity Framework has nothing at all to do with bulk loading anyway

Comment: @rshah4u the duplicate's answer is awful - install Excel on the server? Or install another ETL tool, when SQL Server already includes one?

Comment: You can also use Import Wizard to load the data and *save* the SSIS package. That package can be scheduled to run using SQL Server agent even if the SSIS service isn't configured. In fact, you can load the package in your code and execute it, as shown in [Loading and Running a Local Package Programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/run-manage-packages-programmatically/loading-and-running-a-local-package-programmatically)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sql bulks copy works when column name in excel is same as column name in Db table. Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: You can define the mappings from the input DataTable/DataReader to the target columns.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Thank you i did the same. it works

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries available to read excel data like SpreadsheetGear, NPOI, OLE DB, etc.
You can choose any. 
 I prefer OLE DB, you can interact with excel data in similar way you interact with database.
To store the excel data to database you can use `SqlBulkCopy` class.
You can store the data read from excel file in `System.Data.DataTable` and then use `WriteToServer(DataTable)` method.
Or if you have large excel file you can implement `IDataReader` interface and use method `WriteToServer(IDataReader)`.
The `WriteToServer(IDataReader)` is optimal in case of memory utilization.

Comment: @user1931544 You can specify destination table and column mapping to SQLBulkCopy
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469349/mapping-columns-in-a-datatable-to-a-sql-table-with-sqlbulkcopy